# Gradle compile external dependencies into exploded directory

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to compile a project with Gradle, but when I run it I get a `ClassLoader` error saying that classes in my compile dependencies cannot be found. I see from [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-dependency-management/) that it is possible to include external dependencies in a 'fat jar' through editing the jar group in build.gradle:

```
jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

However, I don't particularly want to package as a jar. Is it possible to do something similar when compiling to an exploded directory?

Also, a second question springs to mind: reflecting on making a 'fat jar' and thinking about the modules system in Java 9, how would one go about compiling external dependencies into modular jars using Gradle?

Comment: Use a copy task rather than a jar task. Or just use the application plugin that will do that for you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I hadn't stumbled across the application plugin. I'll go read up on that, and also check about copy task.